# search user from emailID using RestFB?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I want to search Facebook user from his/email-id. 
Suppose, I have an email of someone who is not in my friend list. How can i search his account using restfb?

I'm trying this `User user = client.fetchObject("emailaddress@emailClient.com", User.class);` but its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t, at least not anymore. You can only use the [Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search) to search for users by name, but not by their email.

Comment: is there any other way to search user from his email? or any way to check any particular  email has FB account?

Comment: no, there is no way. as i said: "you can´t". and you are not supposed to anyway, not without approval of the user. just let them authorize an app with the email permission instead, if you want them to connect their fb account to an email.